# Proxy to substitute particular URLs?

Tags: proxy, http

I need an HTTP proxy which forwards all requests without change, except for some small dynamic subset of URLs, for which content will be substituted for something else.

So for example if you go to http://www.google.com/ the proxy would substitute something funny for Google logo, but leave all other traffic unaffected, including other traffic to www.google.com servers.

Answer (score 1):

Apache httpd or Lighttpd and probably many other HTTP servers, may be configured as a lightweight proxy server. They also can serve whatever you want for the selected URLs and are probably easier to configure for this purpose than squid (which is mainly a caching proxy).

Comment: Good point. Either method should be doable pre April 1st tho :)

Comment: Is there any tutorial document explaining how to configure them for that particular purpose? I imagine something could be hacked based on apache/lighttpd/etc. but has it been done before?

Answer (score 0):

Squid can do that as far as i know. Use a redirector to change out the logo.
[Look here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors) for some info on creating redirectors. Quite a bit of work for a practical joke mind ;)

Comment: Wouldn't redirecting as opposed to substituting on flight mess up with the same origin policy?

Comment: Possibly - but since the OP just wants to fiddle a few images...